# What is the meaning of $form['cid']['#value']?

Tags: 7

```
    /**
     * @Implement of hook_form_alter()
     */
    function mycaptcha_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     if ($form_id == 'comment_form' && !$form['cid']['#value']) {
。。。。。
```

Someone has written the above code, but I don't know what `$form['cid']['#value']` is for, and what I should use in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cid is the comment id. And this comment checks if it is empty or not. When it is not empty, it means that we are editing an existing comment as opposed to creating a new one and this code doesn't need to run.

Comment: could i use !$form['cid']['#value']  in drupal 7?

Comment: It is still named the same way, yes, but you should use empty($form['cid']['#value']) instead, because the current code triggers a notice if it doesn't exist.

Comment: why using empty($form['cid']['#value']) can prevent the notice but !$form['cid']['#value']) not? thank you.

Comment: empty() and isset() do not produce notices, that's what they are for: http://ch2.php.net/empty.