# Confusion as to the meaning of `cid` in webform.module

Tags: nodes, webforms

I'm working on a custom module that will return a single question at a time from an existing webform. For example, from the path `mymodule/(webform_nid)/(question)`.

This is my first encounter with `cid`.

From [the documentation on webform_components_form()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!includes!webform.components.inc/function/webform_components_form/7), it appears that `cid` represents a *component id*. (Elsewhere in the Drupal API documentation and on forums, I have seen it referred to as *comment id*).

Quickly analyzing some test data, it appears that, as a child element of a webform `nid`, **I can reliably use it to sequentially retrieve single questions from a given webform `nid`.**

Am I correct that `cid`s are unique and sequential *per `nid`*? I assume the implementation of `cid` was done to maintain variable name convention.

Or is a `cid` a unique value assigned to each 'component' across the entire site, as its implementation as *comment id* would suggest ([because you can load an existing comment without loading its node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/6085/3852), it would need to be a globally-unique value like `nid`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the `webform_component` table in the database, the description for that field is: "The identifier for this component within this node, starts at 0 for each node."

In my test, however, the first component has a `cid` of 1.  AND - keep in mind that if you delete a component, the next `cid` is incremental - so you can't assume 1 - 6 or whatever.

Comment: I didn't think to check the table comments; they do tend to be decent in Drupal modules. A subtle assumption I made is that component refers only to questions (and not to other things on the webform node).